# Different font for all headings

Tags: fonts, sectioning, sans-serif

I am new to LaTeX and I am trying to use an Arial-like font for all the standard text but a different Sans-Serif font for all the headings. Can somebody please put me in the right direction or an easy-to-understand example?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the `sectsty` package it's easy to do what you want, but the typographic quality of the document will be low: mixing two sans serif fonts is not really *a good thing*. All sans serif is frowned upon by many people, either.

Answer (score 3):

The KOMA classes support this, if you don’t want to do it by hand. For example together with `fontspec` and `xelatex` or `lualatex` you can say:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\fontspec{Arial Black}}

\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
    Some Text.
\end{document}
```